# What is growing on my Anacua tree trunk?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, diseases

A bunch of trees I had ordered finally arrived. None of them are in good shape though I was assured with water and fertilizer they will bounce back. One of the trees, an [Ehretia Anaqua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehretia_anacua), has some odd, misshapen growth up and down the entire trunk.  What is this and is it something I need to worry about? I'd rather return the tree if it's diseased.

[image: Anaqua Tree Trunk Odd Growth]
[image: Anaqua Tree Trunk Odd Growth]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Ehretia anacua, there's something  wrong with it - the bark should just look grey and narrowly furrowed, like the parts around the orangy coloured deposits. The deposits or growths look almost like solidified resin or sap, but I'm not 100% sure that's what they are - whatever they are, they shouldn't be there, nor should some of the bark be hanging off, as I can see it is about halfway down on the right in the second photo. Orange resin deposits present on a tree usually indicate bleeding, and the cause is often a precursor to death or at the very least, a sign of infection or infestation. I note also the leaves do not look healthy - unless your growing  zone is too cold for it and its starting the process of losing its leaves (its frost tender, but evergreen), they look as if they've got rust or some other infection.

I would return it from whence it came and get my money back... image of what the leaves should look like in the link below

http://www.uniprot.org/taxonomy/99303

If the supplier sent this out, I'd be somewhat concerned about the condition of other plants you may have purchased from them - when you buy a plant, it should look in tip top condition, not as if they need to be in an Intensive Care Unit with the distinct possibility of an imminent  move to the Morgue - a little wilting due to stress if they've been in transit a long time is acceptable, maybe some physical damage from being packed, but that's all they should be suffering.

Image of bark in this link (on a mature tree), for confirmation

http://mother-natures-son.com/blog/a-tree-grows-along-the-blanco/

Comment: Based on your feedback, I decided to hire a certified arborist.  Turns out the landscaper tried to pull a fast one or just has no idea what he is doing.  What was suppose to be an Anacua is in fact a Cedar Elm tree.

Comment: Ah! will you return it in hopes of getting an Ehretia? And what's the deal with the lumpy orange stuff and peeling bark....

Comment: Absolutely. I hand picked every tree based on Texas A&M: http://texastreeplanting.tamu.edu/ViewAllTrees.aspx.  Unfortunately I don't remember what he said those growths were...as soon as I found out it wasn't the Ehretia Anaqua, I wanted it gone.

Comment: Whether its a cedar elm or something else, it doesn't look healthy to me - doesn't sound like a good supplier really. Good luck with finding the Ehretia.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, looks like this is completely normal and part of this tree's identity. [Fringe tree bark](http://haufc.org/tree-guide/small/fringe-tree/).

Comment: But it's not a fringe tree.  It's an Anaqua (Ehretia anacua)

Comment: Really, this is what came up under Anaqua and the corky protrusions looked very familiar.  So I am not knowing what an Anaqua tree is, I'll keep watching your question!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this tree is attacked by some kind of fungus. The fungus looks largely widespread. Nothing to do, except wait for it to go away... Unfortunately, the tree won't survive it.

If you have others same species tree and unarmed in the neighborhood, then its probably better to cut that one of and move it away to the local green disposal.